# DrawerLayout with input widgets

Tags: android, android-widget, navigation-drawer

I work on my android application and I would like to create a view with sliding sub-view. The sub-view will contains some widgets such as EditText. Here is my layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:layout_gravity="start"
                      android:background="#0000ff">
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:background="#ffffff">

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I can't switch between EditText widgets. When I click some widget the sliding layout begins to collapse. I thought that is the cause my problem, but I use the following code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);

    return view;
}
```

Left side layout is locked but I still cannot switch between widgets. I tried to change clickable and focusable attribute too.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
        drawerLayout.setClickable(true);
        drawerLayout.setFocusable(true);

        return view;
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't switch between EditText widgets. When I click some widget the
>   sliding layout begins to collapse.

because your widgets is on the main layout and those are not on the sliding menu. so when you click on them it means you click outside of your drawerlayout, your layout is incorrect try this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:background="#ffffff">

    </FrameLayout>

   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="250dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_gravity="start"
                  android:background="#0000ff">
        <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```